# Vagrant + VirtualBox + Dashbrew = not working

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine

I am new to PHP. Coming from the Java - Servlet would, the whole idea of installing virtual machines to do local development is a bit confusing. I am familiar with virtual machines, just not using them for development purposes.

I attempted to use Homestead from Laravel (since this is the framework I'll be using). I have attempted it probably 10 times. Each met with failure. I also attempted to use PuPHPet however I was met with a "File not found" in my browser upon loading it. No matter what tutorial I follow I end up with some kind of issue.

Now I am trying [Dashbrew](https://github.com/mdkholy/dashbrew). A new Vagrant build that is supposed to be simple for beginners. I went through the installation without a hitch. However upon trying to navigate to the dash board for the application (dashbrew.dev) nothing happens. Chrome shows that it is trying to request information, evident by the loading wheel on the tab spinning backwards.

What do I need to do to get this working?

I have MAMP working with Laravel so I could use that. But I wanted to familiarize myself with Vagrant a bit.

If you need any additional information, just leave a comment.

EDIT: Here's what my hosts file looks like...

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

## vagrant-hosts-provisioner-start id: 971cff21-8d99-4aa7-b9b2-ff03403af9f8-0

## vagrant-hosts-provisioner-end

## vagrant-hosts-provisioner-start id: 9b67e862-ea30-4232-9c4a-4c1eb45d8464-0

## vagrant-hosts-provisioner-end

## vagrant-hosts-provisioner-start id: c93caf02-00af-4df0-9d9d-bdaf3c3f34eb-0

## vagrant-hosts-provisioner-end

## vagrant-hosts-provisioner-start id: c83f58db-fd9d-47f1-9aad-685f3e97c6a4-0

## vagrant-hosts-provisioner-end
```

This is what prints in the terminal up running `vagrant up`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I also attempted to use PuPHPet however I was met with a "File not found" in my browser upon loading it. No matter what tutorial I follow I end up with some kind of issue.

This is because you probably didn't have an index file in the vhost's directory.

For example, if your vhost `foo.dev`'s document root is `/var/www/foo.dev/public`, going to http://foo.dev would be hitting your VM's `/var/www/foo.dev/public` directory, looking for an `index.php` file.

Comment: I created a index.php to test. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. chmod the dashbrew directory to 777. I also changed ownership of the dashbrew directory to my username.